# How to change the attributes of specific shapes in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to change the the shadow of the particular object in canvas( NOT all). The problem is that when i tried to give the shadow to the specific object then automatically all other objects also gets the shadow. Here's my code

```
 CanvasState.prototype.draw = function() {
   // if our state is invalid, redraw and validate!
   if (!this.valid) {
     var ctx = this.ctx;
     var shapes = this.shapes;
     this.clear();

     // ** Add stuff you want drawn in the background all the time here **

     // draw all shapes
     var l = shapes.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
       var shape = shapes[i];
       // We can skip the drawing of elements that have moved off the screen:
       if (shape.x > this.width || shape.y > this.height ||
           shape.x + shape.w < 0 || shape.y + shape.h < 0) continue;
       shapes[i].draw(ctx);
     }

     // draw selection
     // right now this is just a stroke along the edge of the selected Shape
     if (this.selection != null) {
       var ctx = this.ctx;
       ctx.strokeStyle = this.selectionColor;
       ctx.lineWidth = this.selectionWidth;
       var mySel = this.selection;
       temp = mySel;

        if (this.light) { 
           ctx.shadowBlur=20;
           ctx.shadowColor="yellow";
        };

       ctx.strokeRect(mySel.x -15,mySel.y -15 ,mySel.w,mySel.h);

       if (del==1) {
         del=0;
         mySel.x=0;
         mySel.y=0;
         mySel.w=0;
         mySel.h=0;
         mySel.r=0;
         mySel.shapes.draw(ctx);

       };

       if (chcolor == 1) {
         chcolor=0;
         mySel.fill = pixelColor;
         mySel.shapes.draw(ctx);
       };

     }

     // ** Add stuff you want drawn on top all the time here **

     this.valid = true;
   }
 }
```

There is if condition for this.light which decides to have shadow or not.

```
 if (this.light) { 
            ctx.shadowBlur=20;
            ctx.shadowColor="yellow";
         };
```

The commands in if condition changes the property of all the shapes in the canvas. So is there any other syntax through which i can change the shadow of the specific shape in canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the shadow right before you want to draw the object with shadow. Afterwards you need to remove the shadow before drawing the rest of the objects.

The simplest way is to use `save()`/`restore()` combined with shadow. For example to integrate you can try something like this (adjust as needed):

```
/// enable shadow for next drawn object
if (this.light) { 
   ctx.save();
   ctx.shadowBlur=20;
   ctx.shadowColor="yellow";
};

/// draw object/shape
ctx.strokeRect(mySel.x -15,mySel.y -15 ,mySel.w,mySel.h);

/// remove shadow
if (this.light) { 
   ctx.restore();
};

... other code...
```

Comment: The changes are been running properly. But for only single shape. When im tring to operate on other shape the previous shape is disabled again. Is there some thing like ctx.mySel.shadowBlur ? Can we do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the native js function setShadow or anyother in the canvas context. You can see it [here](http://uupaa-js-spinoff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/uupaa-excanvas.js/demo/9_1_canvas_shadow_text_direction.html) in action.

Comment: Can you do it same for the shapes ?

Comment: @ketankhandagale yah...u can do the same